# xcode/lldb: process vaporizes when attaching

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

Problem: I have a process, when I attach to it, it immediately exits. The process is built with debug info, I have sources for it, nothing too suspicious.
If I try to use console lldb process attach -pid 
I get initial backtrace, but the process exits imeediately after I type ">c" from Xcode I didn't get even initial backtrace. output is the following:

(lldb) c
Process 71354 resuming
Process 71354 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)

any ideas or suggestion for remedy appreciated. Process is big enough to dig it with half-division method for several weeks, so I'd want to try something else before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is exiting, you can try setting a breakpoint on "exit" before you continue.  Then whoever is causing the exit should be on the stack when you hit the breakpoint.  Maybe that will tell you what is going on.

Comment: I tried, only system code is there. that is only Apple libraries are on the stack